# Automatically publish internal web application

Tags: proxy, paas

I have written a web application that is, typically, installed internally by customers (based on IIS/MSSQL server).

When a customer wants to provide external access to the application, we offer the following supported scenarios:

- Publish the application in their DMZ (pretty standard deployment).
- Use our own platform where we host the application in our own cloud infrastructure for them.

However, because I have more and more customers who misunderstand the requirements for publishing an internal application, I would like to add a "one click" way of providing that service.

My idea is to have a reverse proxy installed on the customer's web server that will connect to a cloud server we control. When the application starts, it will connect to our server, authenticate and maintain the connection. When a user wants to use the application, she will use an URL that directs it to our server (say https://myapp.mycompany.org/CustomerID or https://CustomerID.myapp.mycompany.org). The server will then lookup the list of connections from reverse proxy to find the one matching the customer ID and, if found, use that connection to relay the end user connection.

In essence, that is the same thing as what Azure Application proxy or TeamViewer do, only without the need for using Azure AD or TeamViewer.

Is there an existing framework I can use for building such a service ? I know I can write it on my own but that is quite a large development.